# Windows 2008 terminal server - How to restrict access to DVD/floppy?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy, terminal-server, removable-storage

I has a very simple task.
I need to block access to removable media (CD, DVD, floppy, USB drives etc.) on a Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Server for users and allow it for admins.

I tried to enable the following policy in GPO:------

User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Removable Storage Access

> All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access = Enabled

But it did not work. 
I tried different physical and virtual 2008 servers with the same result.
It works on Windows 7 but not on Windows 2008.

Has anyone had success with this parameter on Windows 2008?

Thank you

Comment: Disable the device under device manager, an admin could go turn it back on when they need it.

Comment: This is good if admins know that the devices were disabled this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Microsoft. 
They confirmed that this is "undocumented behavior".
So this policy is not working "by design" on W2K8 Terminal Server if applied via User GPO.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the same policy in *Computer Configuration* section. The User Configuration setting is inconsequential because the Computer Configuration policy overrides.

Link GPO to the OU where terminal server resides.Then configure *Security Filtering* to apply settings in GPO to the users/groups/computers you need (i.e. your users and terminal server).

Comment: If I put this in Computer policies, it will be applied to all users including administrators. I want administrators to be able to have access to DVD. I am not sure that security filering on computer policies will have effect on user groups.

Comment: That's the point, with Security Filtering you can apply settings ONLY to the users/groups/computers you need.

Comment: Not sure to understand. If the parameter is set in the Computer policy it will apply to computer objects only and won't apply to user profiles. So if I do as you recommend, I will get the policy applied to the whole computer, which will block the access for all users including admins, which I do not want.

Comment: Yes, seems like you are right. I thought there is an exception for Computer Settings, like there's for User Settings (i.e. [loopback processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287), if user needs to have policies applied based on the location of the computer).

Comment: Perhaps, logon script which will disable access to removable devices is what you need.